# unckeck the other Checkbox in checkboxlist if the other one is selected

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="ckbLstPartner" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="cssRdlstMoheSacm">
<asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

how to uncheck the other option if one of them is selected by JQuery

Comment: Please try some jQuery code first and then update your question with more code otherwise people don't take too kindly to `here's what I have, please write the rest for me`. It will also be helpful if you show the actual HTML from the web browser and not ASP.

Comment: Also this is a possible duplicate question, did you even google your question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17302317/how-to-uncheck-select-all-checkbox-when-one-checkbox-is-unchecked

Comment: If only one is checked, use RadioButtonList.

Comment: If anybody wants to help, please give the advice. but don't ask me to google my question. I know when I've to google it.   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In aspx page:

```
<script>
        function radioMe(e) {
            if (!e) e = window.event;
            var sender = e.target || e.srcElement;

            if (sender.nodeName != 'INPUT') return;
            var checker = sender;
            var chkBox = document.getElementById('<%= ckbLstPartner.ClientID %>');
            var chks = chkBox.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
            for (i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
                if (chks[i] != checker)
                    chks[i].checked = false;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

In code behind Page Load event

```
ckbLstPartner.Attributes.Add("onclick", "radioMe(event);");
```